# RunApex missing method parameter with ClickToDial on objects with special characters in the name

Tags: javascript, opencti

I am using a custom console component that listens to ClickToDial events and calls the sforce.interaction.runApex method from the openCTI API.

```
sforce.interaction.cti.onClickToDial(function(clickToDialResponse) {
    if (clickToDialResponse.error) {
        console.log(clickToDialResponse.error);
        return;
    }

    sforce.interaction.runApex('ClickToDialHandler', 'HandleClickToDial', 'clickToDialResultJson=' + clickToDialResponse.result, function(response) {
        if (response.error) {
            console.log(response.error);
            return;
        }

        //else do something with response.result
    }
};
```

One of the parameters I am passing to my Apex method is the name of the object the ClickToDial was initiated from (as found in the JSON from the ClickToDial event).

If I initiate a ClickToDial from an object with '&' in the name, I see a missing method error in the browser development tools console.

[image: Error seen in Chrome DevTools]

The runApex call uses a POST to Salesforce, and all the parameters appear to be url encoded. Is there something I can do to fix this, or is this a bug with Salesforce?